# python ngram reducer not returning any output?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, mapreduce

I am trying to build a mapreduce job for ngrams of google books. My mapper works fine when tested locally but the reducer does not returns any value. The reducer is something like below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys

current_word = ''
word_in_progress = ''
target_year_count = 0   
prior_year_count = 0
target_year = 1999

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip().split('\t')
    if len(line) !=3:
        continue
    current_word, year, occurances = line

    if current_word != word_in_progress:
        if target_year_count > 0:
            if prior_year_count ==0:
                print '%s\t%s' % (word_in_progress, target_year_count)
    try:
        year = int(year)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    try:
        occurances = int(occurances)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    if year == target_year:
        target_year_count += occurances
    if year < target_year:
        prior_year_count += occurances
            print '%s\t%s' % (word_in_progress, target_year_count)
if target_year_count > 0:
    if prior_year_count ==0:
        print '%s\t%s' % (word_in_progress, target_year_count)
```

And when I type the below command in Ubuntu command line:

```
hduser@bharti-desktop:~/hadoop$ cat /home/hduser/Documents/test1.1.txt | /home/hduser /hadoop/mapper-ngram.py | sort -k1,1 | /home/hduser/hadoop/reducerngram1.py| sort -k2,2n
```

I get nothing. Could somebody tell me what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd check:

```
cat /home/hduser/Documents/test1.1.txt | /home/hduser /hadoop/mapper-ngram.py | sort -k1,1 | /home/hduser/hadoop/reducerngram1.py| sort -k2,2n
                                                     ^ # Is this space a typo?
```

Is this space a typo in your post, or did you really run the command that way?  If this is an accurate representation of your command, I'm guessing the input's not actually getting to your mapper (and therefore nothing will get to your reducer).